# version especifica crystal reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

Tengo un problema con una aplicación desarrollada en C#, en mi entorno de desarrollo tengo instalado Crystal reports y la version de las librerias usadas es la 13.0.3500.0.

En las maquinas de produccion esta instalada la misma versión de librerias con el runtime y la aplicación funciona sin inconveniente.

Tengo unas maquinas en las que se instalo la version 13.0.4000.0 del runtime y al tratar de ejecutar la aplicación me arroja error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hay alguna forma de configurar en Visual Studio que si la version del runtime es mayor a la que se uso en la aplicación permita ejecutar?

Ya intente en las propiedades del proyecto poner "false" en la version especifica de las librerias de crystal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: Usa copia local = True, porque como no está en el GAC esa versión de CR, entonces indicale que use el .dll que con el que vas a compilar. Mas info en inglés [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602765/when-should-copy-local-be-set-to-true-and-when-should-it-not)

Comment: @javdromero gracias, ya intente hacer eso y tampoco funciona, el se va primero al GAC y toma las dll mas nuevas y arroja el errror.

Comment: Al parecer [no se puede hacer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267693/how-can-i-force-net-to-use-a-local-copy-of-an-assembly-thats-in-the-gac), se me ocurre ahora que incluyas [instalar las dll en el gac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182316/how-do-i-register-a-net-dll-file-in-the-gac) y probar si eso funciona

Comment: Gracias pero no es posible, creo que la solucion viable sera migrar la aplicacion en la operacion a la ultima version de crystal .